# Splitting strings in a "Google" style way

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, string, split

I am trying to create a function that will split a string into search terms. Using this code will work fine:

```
string TestString = "This is a test";
string[] Terms;
Terms = TestString.Split(" ");
```

This will split my string into 4 strings: "This", "is", "a", "test".
However I want words that are enclosed in quotes to be treated as one word:

```
string TestString = "This \"test will\" fail";
string[] Terms;
Terms = TestString.Split(" ");
```

This will split my string into 4 strings, again: "This", "\"test", "will\"", "fail"

What I want is for it split that last string into only 3 strings: "This", "test will", "fail"

Anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a Regex:

```
var testString = "This \"test will\" fail";
var termsMatches = Regex.Matches(testString, "(\\w+)|\"([\\w ]+[^ ])\"");
```

Comment: For extra credit: get the regex to handle quotes embedded in the quoted portion. Your choice of how to escape the embedded quotes - using `\\`, by doubling up the quotes, or some other mechanism. But single quotes have to be embeddable as well (as do backslashes).